# Firebase failed to bounce to type when retrieving

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was having some problem when trying to retrieve from Firebase. Here is my "Users" table in firebase:

I am trying to store like a user with multiple fields. Am I storing it wrong?
[image]

My Users.java:

```
public class Users {
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}

private String userName;
private String password;
private String address;
private String phone;
private String email;
private String question;
private String answer;

}
```

The part when I try to retrieve the JSON from Firebase:

```
btnSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating firebase object
            Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
            //Value event listener for realtime data update
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //Getting the data from snapshot
                        Users user = postSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                        System.out.println(user.getUserName()); //Testing

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

However, I am getting these error messages:

```
07-01 11:32:50.735 1025-1025/com.apps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
    at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:185)
    at com.gabrielheng.zhapalangapps.Login$1$1.onDataChange(Login.java:49)
    at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
    at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
    at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "gab" (class Entity.Users), not marked as ignorable (7 known properties: , "address", "question", "userName", "password", "email", "answer", "phone"])
    at [Source: java.io.StringReader@416d8540; line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: Entity.Users["gab"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1160)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
    at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
    at com.gabrielheng.zhapalangapps.Login$1$1.onDataChange(Login.java:49) 
    at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45) 
    at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45) 
    at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
07-01 11:32:50.790 1025-1026/com.apps D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 456K, 13% free 9663K/11015K, paused 21ms+7ms
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is explicitly mention in the stack trace:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "gab" (class Entity.Users), not marked as ignorable (7 known properties: , "address", "question", "userName", "password", "email", "answer", "phone"])

Since your JSON doesn't have a property called `gab`, it seems like you're simply reading the data at the wrong level in your JSON tree.

The solution is to attach your listener one level lower in the tree on the `Users` node:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
//Value event listener for realtime data update
ref.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
```

Comment: I see I see. Sorry my bad. I forgot that I added a child level to sort it out so that my data is much clearer. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

Your `Users` class needs a no-arg constuctor:

```
public Users() {
}
```

This is explained in [the documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html).

> Instead of dealing with the primitives types, we'll do what we did
>   when saving users. We'll create a Java class that represents a Blog
>   Post. Like last time, we have to make sure that our field names match
>   the names of the properties in the Firebase database and **give the
>   class a default, parameterless constructor**.

Comment: If your class defines no constructors, the compiler will generate a default no-args constructor, which the Firebase code will find using reflection. While I typically would not rely on this compiler behavior, the lack of an explicit no-args constructor should not be causing the problem here.

Comment: @Frank:  Ooops.  My bad.  I haven't used the old version of Firebase and was relying on the docs. ;-)

Comment: @qbix Hey but that does not solve the problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The docs are unmodified in that sense. The guide will document the recommended practice, which is to include such a constructor (even when it's technically not needed). But it isn't the cause of this error. My answer below *is* the cause. As usual, the details are in the stack trace, although (also as usual) not easy to parse.

Comment: @BobSnyder You saved my life